# Need Shortcut keys for JOption(javax.swing) /Jidesoft(com.jidesoft.dialog) Error dialog

Tags: swing, joptionpane, shortcut, hotkeys, jide

I am Using following code,

```
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("<html>Map Following data:\n WTXFF,WTXF");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(sb1.toString())); Object[] options = new Object[] {"ShowMappingTable" , "Cancel", };
        int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(getWindow(), scrollPane, "Error ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
```

[image]

How can I add Hot keys to the ShowMappingTable and Cancel button.
I greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to make a completely custom dialog to be able to assign your own accelerators. Unfortunately that usually requires much more coding.
Check [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for the best alternative for you.